# How to handle errors and keep an Observable alive in .mapParallelUnordered

Tags: scala, observable, monix

I am using `Monix 3` and have a kind of this code:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
    .flatMap(i =>
      if (i % 2 == 0) {   // Bad i
        Observable.empty
      } else
        Observable.pure(i)
    )
    .foreachL(i => print(s"Good i: $i"))   /*Output: Good i: 1
                                                     Good i: 3
                                                     Good i: 5
                                                     Good i: 7
                                                     Good i: 9*/
```

This code works good, but I have a numerous long while IO operations, so decided to refactor with `.mapParallelUnordered`:

```
  Observable.fromIterable(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
    .mapParallelOrdered(3)(i =>
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        Task.raiseError(new Exception(s"Bad i: $i"))
      } else
        Task.pure(i)
    )
    .foreachL(i => print(s"Good i: $i"))    /*Output: Good i: 1*/
```

I am trying to get the same result, as in the first example, but in parallel processing. The problem is `Task.raiseError` kills a whole observable, so it stops on `i = 2`.

How to handle errors and  keep an Observable alive?

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you're trying to achieve. Maybe try to explain your situation a little more next time.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Updated Question: I am trying to get the same result, as in the first example, but in a parallel processing. The problem is `Task.raiseError` kills a whole observable, so it stops on `i = 2`.

Comment: I need to understand why you use `Task.raiseError` in your example. What does it stand for? Do you want to "filter" out any I/O operations that don't succeed?

Comment: @MarkusAppel Yep. Some operations can be failed. In the first example i can recover with `Observable.empty`, and this skip all the following operations, e.g `foreachL ...`. But first example doesnt run in parallel. The second one runs in parallel, but i dont know, how to skip failed operations.

Comment: There are cats instances for `Observable` that might be interesting for you, more specifically [`MonadError`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/MonadError.scala) and [`ApplicativeError`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/ApplicativeError.scala). Try to see if one of these work for you. I wish I could compile an example for you but it seems ScalaFiddle and Scastie don't have the correct versions of the two libraries.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Can you show me. how to use it with my case in answer?

Comment: @Oleg I added `scala` tag to your question. Language tags are most observed and therefore adding it might get more attention to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Observable
  .fromIterable(Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
  .mapParallelOrdered(3)(
    i =>
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        Task.pure(Left("Error"))
      } else
        Task.pure(Right(i))
  )
  .collect {
    case Right(i) => i
  }
  .foreachL(i => print(s"Good i: $i"))
```